# Gmail/Facebook chat - iframa, ajax, url anchors, but what about indexing?

Tags: ajax, iframe, indexing, googlebot

I'm still not sure how it works(but it's not the point:D). As far as I noticed, whole content(almost:D) is in the iframe and chat window is outside iframe. Request are probably made via ajax, and urls are changing like this const_part_of_url#something - so the only url anchors(or whatever it's called) are changing.

2 things bothering me :

- What about googlebot, is it able to index those pages correctly(not gmail, but say some web page with similar "technology" used), 1st beacuse of iframe, 2nd because of only anchor changes in urls?
- Is it possible to make some part of url changing not only anchors?

The thing is I have an mp3 search engine where you can listen these mp3s too, and this kind of floating, "not-reloading" player with playlist would be kinda cool:D But I'm very concern about proper page indexing and other SEO blah blah... so I don't really now if it's worth trying:D

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can detect robots and not feed them with user-eyes-only content ...

Edit : you can also load it on demand (javascript)... bots wont load it

Comment: That's of course one of the possible solutions, but you have to prepare two versions of the site(ok, not exactly two, cause there will be lot of shared content) and if googlebot discovers two different versions(one for users, one for robots) it can be treated as cloaking... From the other hand it doesn't sound like a bad idea, if nothing better comes up, I'll probably try:D

Comment: I think, I'll use ajax to reload some part of the content. I'll test it first to see how google bot can handle:D